# ContextMenuStrip in c# tray application not reacting correctly when in expanded icon window

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have made a tray application with an icon that opens a **ContextMenuStrip** on Icon Click. I have three **ToolStripMenuItem** that can be clicked.

The Tray Application is working fine as long as the icon is visible directly. However if I have to click on the chevron to expand the non visible tray icons, I run into one Problem. 
I can open the Menu by click on the Item. If I click on one of the **ToolStripMenuItems** the Tray-Menu goes into the Background of the Expanded Tray Icons and cannot be clicked anymore. How can I prevent this? 
It seems the background is capturing the click rather then the openend form.

Here is the code for the Menu.

```
class Menu
{
    private static ContextMenuStrip contextMenuStrip;
    private static NotifyIcon notifyIcon1 = new NotifyIcon();
    public Menu()  
    {
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("icon.ico");
        notifyIcon1.Text = "icon";
        contextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripItem stripItem0 = new ToolStripMenuItem("open");
        contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { stripItem0 });
        ToolStripItem stripItem1 = new ToolStripMenuItem("stop");
        stripItem1.Click += new EventHandler(ToggleTracking);
        contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { stripItem1 });
        ToolStripItem line = new ToolStripSeparator();
        contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { line });
        ToolStripItem stripItem2 = new ToolStripMenuItem("close");
        stripItem2.Click += new EventHandler(Close);
        contextMenuStrip.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { stripItem2 });

        notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip;
        //notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1;
        notifyIcon1.Click += new EventHandler(IconClick);
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void ToggleTracking(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem stripItem1 = (ToolStripMenuItem)contextMenuStrip.Items[1];
        if (stripItem1.Text == "stop")
        {
            stripItem1.Text = "restart";
            Batch.StopTimer();
        }
        else
        {
            stripItem1.Text = "stop";
            Batch.RestartTimer();
        }
    }

    private void Close(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    private void IconClick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control strip = Sender as Control;
        if (contextMenuStrip.Visible)
        {
            contextMenuStrip.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            contextMenuStrip.Show(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't duplicate that behavior.  What are you doing with that timer?

Comment: At the moment the timer ist just writing something to the console. I just want to test if the click is working or not. The Behaviour is strange it does not allways happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use the BringToFront method like this.

```
{
    contextMenuStrip.Show(Cursor.Position);
    contextMenuStrip.BringToFront();
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx